# Colors change on a picture during a print job when printing from Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, printing, printer

I've got a problem when printing from LR6 (but also in previous versions and on different computers). Before getting a new computer and a new printer, I've suspected that it is a printer problem but after getting a new computer and a new printer (first one was a Brother inkjet printer, current one is a Canon inkjet one), the problem persists. If I print several pictures, the colors are correct at the beginning, but at some point on a picture, colors become darker.

There is enough ink available and the problem is not related to a specific color. It starts at a straight line after that the colors change. The following schema illustrates the problem (the pictures in the print job are separated by blanks):

```
CCC CCC CCD DDD DDD
CCC CCC CCD DDD DDD
```

At the beginning, zero or several pictures are printed with correct colors (C). Somewhere in the print job, the colors become to dark (D). The subsequent pictures are printed with darker colors. If I start a new print job, colors are correct again.

Comment: @mattdm: thanks for the hint. I've updated the title.

Comment: Is printer profile fixed somewhere in Lightroom or you let it pick one from Windows colour management list?

Comment: @EuriPinhollow I let Lightroom do the color management, but it doesn't seem to be related to the color profile, as the colors change in mid-print. Before the change, the colors are good.

Comment: The question stands. The phrase "Lightroom manages colours" means that you select the printer profile somewhere in Lightroom. Also, can you reproduce the problem in other programs? It would be nice if your tried XnViewMP and GIMP.

Comment: @EuriPinhollow yes, Lightroom does the color management. Unfortunately, the problem cannot be reproduced easily. In fact, it hasn't occured during the last prints (I left Lightroom open while printing). Maybe that is the solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: do not hesitate to report any updates.

Comment: Do you see the color change in preview? How do you print multiple images on the same sheet? Can you rule out any overlay? Does it happen even if you print one image on one sheet? What kind of paper you use? Does it happen with any paper or just one type/package? Did you try to inspect the transition C->D under some magnification? Does it seem pixel related? Printer point related? Independent on the above? When printing, does your printer slow down in the middle?

Comment: @MirekE thanks for your help. I think I got the issue sorted out. It seems to happen only if I close Lightroom in the middle of a print job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to keep Lightroom open while the print job is still running. If I close Lightroom when the printer is still emitting pages, the colors change as described.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the complete set of inks. Ifound this sometimes with Epsons.

Comment: The ink containers were almost full. So the effect was not related to this. Thanks for your help.